# Чем хороши книги Кнута "Искусство программирования"?

Tags: книги

Подойдут ли они для прочтения новичку для понимания алгоритмов?

Comment: Традиции. Написал бы я такую же книгу и даже лучше - мало кто хвалил бы и через год и через пять лет. У информатики англосаксонские корни, для них это доминирующая форма мышления. Паскаль как первый язык - туда же.

Comment: У германцев - иное: прочитает одну главу, увидит незначительную пользу, но помножит ее на число глав и скажет "хорошая книга". У французов - третье: пролистает всю, ощутит значительную пользу, скажет "хорошая".

Comment: Новичку **обязательно** нужно почитать книги про алгоритмы. Не обязательно Кнута.

Comment: @Rou1997: Что ж вы так немцев-то не любите?

Comment: @Rou1997: Напиши вы такую книгу, как TAOCP, вы бы работали техлидом в компании по вашему выбору.

Comment: @VladD У немецкого мышления свои плюсы и минусы, у меня самого похожий склад ума (немцы, китайцы, цыгане - все это близко. хоть есть и различия), в одних случаях он хорош, в других плох и нужно тренировать иные подходы, а считать человека идеальным нарочно игнорируя недостатки это не любовь к нему, а коварная подстава.

Comment: @VladD Очень нескоро моя книга бы поимела успех. А то можно взять Кнута, "повысить оригинальность". заменить обложку и вперед. Но покупать не будут, куча народу советует Кнута просто потому что так привыкли, попробуй их переубеди.

Comment: @Rou1997: Я, честно говоря, не представляю себе, чтобы немец мог не дочитать несколько глав и положиться на _индукцию_. В моём представлении о немецком мышлении немец скорее перепроверил бы все вычисления и нашёл бы 189 ошибок в пятнадцатом и старше десятичных знаках, и привёл бы их в табличном виде.

Comment: @Rou1997: Мне, допустим, чтобы написать такую книгу как TAOCP, необходимо ещё примерно в тысячу раз больше программистской, в 100 раз больше математической эрудиции, и в бесконечное количество раз больше чувства юмора. Вы настолько эрудированы, что способны написать такую же книгу самостоятельно? Круто, очень завидую вам.

Comment: @VladD Да немцы очень хорошо умеют исследовать, проверять и доводить до идеала, но почему вы упускаете из виду ограниченность ресурсов мозга? Именно из-за излишней фокусировки на одних аспектах (там, где другие просто сделали бы как попало), немцы могут упускать другие и тратят много времени, так получаются вечные двигатели (автор просто запутывает себя, усложняя конструкцию), пушка "Дора" (почему-то их не напрягло, что это будет стрельба вслепую), или война с СССР с дедлайном в 2 месяца, растянувшаяся на 5 лет. И все это - именно немецкие темы.

Comment: Да, немцы известны тем, что сосредотачиваются на конкретике, упуская общее. Ну а планы на блицкриг у них были вследствие истеричности (очень не-немецкой) их тогдашнего фюрера. Но в любом случае это вроде не противоречит тезису о том, что немец таки дочитает всю книгу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что эти книги базовые и фундаментальные. Они освещают все вопросы очень глубоко, и рассматривают их не с точки зрения конкретного языка или конкретной технологии, а с точки зрения составления алгоритмов и правильного мышления. Окей и не оставляют пробелов в темах, которые рассматривают.

Они учат программировать, правильному подходу учёного, а не ремесленника. Базовый вопрос у Кнута — не *как решать задачу*, а *какой способ решения задачи наилучший в данных обстоятельствах*.

Answer (score -1):

Потому, что они дают все базовые и не очень академические знания по многим вопросам программирования